# Jump to Bundle?

Tags: experience-manager, bundles

When working on an activity (in Experience Manager) from the task view I can open the Bundle but I can't seem to easily get to its location in the Content Manager Explorer.

I can use the BluePrint viewer, but am I missing something?

With a Bundle open, is there an "shortcut" to its location in the Content Manager Explorer (though I'd prefer its contents instead of its location)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no shortcut that I know of. It would be nice if you could click the thumbnail, and also if there was an option somewhere to explore organizational items like Bundles, Folders, etc.

Anyway, if you need this often, you can try the following JavaScript code:

```
var selection = new Tridion.Cme.Selection();
selection.addItem($display.getUri());
$commands.executeCommand("Explore", selection);
```

Use it on the Bundle editing screen and it should open the list of items within the Bundle.

You could easily make a bookmarklet out of this by copying the code, creating a new bookmark in your browser, typing "javascript:" and then pasting in the code. Then you can click the bookmark any time you need to explore the current item in the CME.

Comment: I've seen customers add "edit item" links directly on Component Presentation, which basically moves the "Open" button closer to the items. I think the "explore folder" idea would be nice there. So something like "from the context of a selected item in XPM, present a shortcut to where the item lives." Thanks for the script. I'll add this to Ideas.